# Python - TypeError occured while using pickle - how to use it correct

Tags: python, file, pickle

I want to use pickle to safe some strings and compare the strings from yesterday with the strings from today.

```
filename = filename + '_yesterday.txt'
with open(filename, 'w+') as myfile:
     # if empty write something
     if os.path.getsize(myfile) == 0:
         myfile.write('write something')
     old_strings = pickle.load(myfile)
     all_strings = '....'

with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
     pickle.dump(all_strings, myfile)
```

First question: Why I can't use an var-name for the file
I always get this exception.

```
 with open(filename, 'w+') as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

second question: 
I get this exception if I use it with an existing file:

```
          if os.path.getsize(myfile) == 0:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Comment: is your indentation correct

Comment: @VigneshKalai sry now it is correct.

Comment: could you print the file name

Comment: python 2 or 3? I think your using unicode filenames

Comment: @VigneshKalai already done and it is fine. I reduce the code to: with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
            old_str = pickle.load(myfile)  - and it still doesn't work out I get: File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError

Comment: @muddyfish python 2.7

Comment: @VigneshKalai that is for example a file name 'https://website.de/_oldstrings.txt'

Comment: @Loretta `/` is windows mean a new directory is there a directory like `website.de`

Comment: @Loretta for example `with open("a/a.txt","w") as out:
    ...:     out.write("yes")
    ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-f62415555c2a> in <module>()
----> 1 with open("a/a.txt","w") as out:
      2     out.write("yes")
      3 

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a/a.txt' 
` this is due to the fact I don't have a directory in the name a

Comment: I did it now like this and it works with open(name, 'rb+') as fp:
        try:
            return pickle.load(fp)
        except:
            fp.truncate(0)
            pickle.dump(default, fp)
            return default

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file with the mode `'wb+'`

Comment: why wb+ ? I recognized that if the file has '(lp0 .' as a string it works out? why?

Comment: but I have still the problem with a var filename and not a string - with open(filename, 'rb+') as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: You use wb+ because I was assuming you knew what you were doing when you assigned the `'w+'` mode. I know also that pickles in the mode you chose are binary files. In most os's, you need to add the `'b'` to the mode in order to write not ascii.

Comment: To fix the other problem, look at @hspandher's answer

Comment: but why it dosen't work out if my file dosen't has '(lp0 .' inside ? File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError

Comment: I would ask another question if this is a different problem - it looks like it is because the code you posted in te question doesnt look like it's at all relevent to what the new error is

Answer (score 1):

`os.stat` requires filepath as an argument instead of file object. This is causing the error when you are doing `if os.path.getsize(myfile) == 0`.